# MATLAB: Stacking .figs

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, stacked-area-chart

I'm currently working on a study about fuel consumption. I have multiple .fig files that shows the trend of fuel consumption in L/100 Km versus Time. I have multiple cases showing the behavior of the plot under different conditions, and I wan't to show the differences between them. An example of the plot is shown below:

[image]

Is there anyway to stack plots from different .fig files in 1 .fig file?

Comment: Are you generating those figures, or do you have them saved in files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you'd want to generate those different plots using [subplot](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html).

Your exact question has been answered by ZiV in the [mathworks forums](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/282820):

> One way to do this is to extract xdata and ydata from existing
>   figures, then re-plot these data in a new figure window as desired.
>   For example,

```
open('gugu.fig');
h_gugu=get(gca,'Children');
x_gugu=get(h_gugu,'XData');
y_gugu=get(h_gugu,'YData');

open('lulu.fig');
h_lulu=get(gca,'Children');
x_lulu=get(h_lulu,'XData');
y_lulu=get(h_lulu,'YData');

figure
subplot(121)
plot(x_gugu,y_gugu);
subplot(122)
plot(x_lulu,y_lulu)
saveas(gcf,'gugululu','fig')
```

Comment: Yes, `hold on` will help plotting all the graphs in the same axes. `subplot` is used to _tile_ the graphs.

Comment: Oh! I see now, the posted snippet worked for me. I'm gonna try Hold On as well though

Comment: You do not need to re-plot the data; you can copy the graphs using `copyobj()`.